# Validate a Timecode in tk.Entry Widget

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I have the following code to only allow the entry of a valid timecode, but I cannot enter the colon myself (which I would like to do though). As soon as I enter three numbers and the third number is thereby automatically replaced with a colon, the validation completely stops and I can continuously enter what I want because the validation no longer works. What could be the reason for this error?

```py
runtime_label = tk.Label(metadata_window, text="Runtime (01:30:20:10):", background=GUI_BG_COLOR,
                            foreground=GUI_TEXT_COLOR)
runtime_label.pack(padx=0, pady=8)
self.runtime_entry = tk.Entry(metadata_window, background="#333333", foreground=GUI_TEXT_COLOR, width=42,
                                textvariable=runtime_var, validate="key")
self.runtime_entry.pack()
validate_runtime_entry_command = metadata_window.register(self.validate_runtime_entry)
self.runtime_entry.config(validatecommand=(validate_runtime_entry_command, '%S'))

def validate_runtime_entry(self, input):
    time_str = self.runtime_entry.get().strip()
    if input.isdigit() and len(time_str.replace(':', '')) < 8:
        # Add colon after every two digits
        if len(time_str.replace(':', '')) in [2, 4, 6]:
            self.runtime_entry.insert(len(time_str), ':')
            return False  # force revalidation to check new format
        return True
    elif input == '\b':
        return True
    else:
        try:
            # Check format first
            datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S:%f')
            # Then check if it's a valid time
            h, m, s, f = map(int, time_str.split(':'))
            if not (0 <= h <= 23 and 0 <= m <= 59 and 0 <= s <= 59 and 0 <= f <= 47):
                raise ValueError
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

I have tried to change the function and reduce (the one with the colons) but I never get the desired result that only one timecode can be entered.

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If the validation function throws an error, it automatically disables validation. You need to make sure that the validation function always returns either `True` or `False`.

Also, the validation is designed for validation only. You shouldn't be modifying the widget within the validation function. This is another case where tkinter will automatically disable the validation feature.

This is what the [canonical tcl/tk documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) has to say about it:

> In general, the -**textvariable** and -**validatecommand** options can be dangerous to mix. Any problems have been overcome so that using the -**validatecommand** will not interfere with the traditional behavior of the entry widget. Using the -**textvariable** for read-only purposes will never cause problems. The danger comes when you try set the -**textvariable** to something that the -**validatecommand** would not accept, which causes -**validate** to become none (the -**invalidcommand** will not be triggered). The same happens when an error occurs evaluating the -**validatecommand**.
>
> Primarily, an error will occur when the -**validatecommand** or -**invalidcommand** encounters an error in its script while evaluating or -**validatecommand** does not return a valid Tcl boolean value. The -**validate** option will also set itself to none when you edit the entry widget from within either the -**validatecommand** or the -**invalidcommand**. Such editions will override the one that was being validated. If you wish to edit the entry widget (for example set it to {}) during validation and still have the -**validate** option set, you should include the command

Comment: Thank you. Now I have solved it this way. But unfortunately this is not a good and acceptable solution.
`    def validate_runtime_entry(text):
        if text == "":
            return True

        allowed_chars = set(":0123456789")
        if set(text) <= allowed_chars:
            return True

        return False`
However, it later shatters the program as soon as you accidentally enter one digit too many or too few. At some point the colons are resolved (so that there are still 8 digits) - however, this does not work reliably in case of a wrong entry.